# SwitchPreference create programmatically, setChecked not working

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, android-preference-v14

I want to

1. create a `SwitchPreference` programmatically
2. set `setChecked(true)` on it
3. add it to a `PreferenceGroup`

1 and 3 work fine, but after 3 the `SwitchPreference` is not checked and clicks on the toggle have no effect (can't be 'turned on'/ checked).

Here's my `PreferenceFragment`:

```
public class MyPrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(final Bundle savedInstanceState, final String rootKey) {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

        PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup = (PreferenceGroup) findPreference("pref_cat_1");

        SwitchPreference switchPreference = new SwitchPreference(getActivity());
        switchPreference.setTitle("new");
        switchPreference.setChecked(true);
        switchPreference.setDefaultValue(true);

        switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), newValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

        preferenceGroup.addPreference(switchPreference);

    }
}
```

and my `PreferenceScreen`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="cat_one">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="pref_1"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:title="fest"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="pref_cat_1"
        android:title="category"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

How can I properly `setChecked(true)` on a SwitchPreference that was created programmatically?

Test project is [on Github](https://github.com/fweigl/PrefThrowAway).

Comment: I hit the same problem... calling `addPreference` on a `PreferenceCategory` which already has a `SwitchPreference` in it caused the issue for me... my workaround was to refactor the code to not use `addPreference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **SwitchPreference** is not checked and clicks on the toggle have no effect.

It is checked on my machine. Concerning the state after clicking on it you are totally right. That's because you are returning `false` from `onPreferenceChange()` callback.

Documentation of `onPreferenceChange()`:

> Returns: **true** to update the state of the Preference with the new value.

So, I've only changed `false` to `true` and it works as expected.

**EDIT**

I was running API 25 tablet emulator. Then ran on API 22 emulator, and it didn't work. It's very strange, that it runs as expected only on API 25.

Comment: @Ascorbin did you ever end up getting this working on lower API levels?

Comment: @ForrestBice Nope.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on using `addPreference()`, but I switch to `preferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(switchPreference)` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I tried this solution. not working on my side. See my quetion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73982273/programatic-switchpreference-always-unchecked