# Programatic SwitchPreference Always Unchecked

Tags: android, preference, switchpreference

I added 3 switch preference in a PreferenceCategory programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:persistent="true">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="my_key"
        android:title="TEST" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the code for adding switch preferences.

```
PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup = (PreferenceGroup) findPreference("my_key");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    SwitchPreference switchPreference = new SwitchPreference(getActivity());
    switchPreference.setTitle(title);
    switchPreference.setKey(key);
    switchPreference.setDefaultValue(true);
    switchPreference.setChecked(true);

    preferenceGroup.addPreference(switchPreference);
}
```

The screen shows like below. **They're all unchecked**. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Tried preferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(switchPreference), but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting the default value programmatically.